# canvas.DrawPath not drawn when giving the long value in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-canvas

I am working in Xamarin android.

Sample code:

```
Path.MoveTo(22020100.00,22020100.00)
```

I am trying to draw the line from this position but it is not drawn when providing the long value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to draw a line:

the first method:

```
canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
```

the second method:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);  // When drawing a line using a path, specify that the Paint Style is STROKE. Otherwise Paint will use the default style-fill. This Style does not create a line using a path
paint.Color = Color.Red;
Path path = new Path();
path.MoveTo(22020100.00f, 22020100.00f);
path.LineTo(120, 250);
canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: @Santhiya Both methods work on my side, can you show me more code?